# useRef.current is undefined even in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am a beginner to react and react-native. I am trying to set up Firebase for analytics. I am using react-native-redux with react-native-redux-persist. Also using react-naviagation.

The code from App.js in my react native app:

```
const App = () => {
  const routeNameRef = React.useRef(null);
  const navigationRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hrhr');
    console.log(routeNameRef);
    console.log(navigationRef);
    const state = navigationRef.current.getRootState();

    // Save the initial route name
    routeNameRef.current = getActiveRouteName(state);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={persistStore.store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore.persistor}>
        <NavigationContainer
          ref={navigationRef}
          onStateChange={state => {
            const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
            const currentRouteName = getActiveRouteName(state);

            if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
              // The line below uses the @react-native-firebase/analytics tracker
              // Change this line to use another Mobile analytics SDK
              analytics().setCurrentScreen(currentRouteName, currentRouteName);
            }

            // Save the current route name for later comparision
            routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
          }}>
           {/***/}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Logs:

```
LOG  hrhr
LOG  {"current": undefined}
LOG  {"current": undefined}
```

Versions:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

The app also has dependencies on react native redux and firebase.

**UPDATE**

useEffect is sometimes being called on loop after the app reloads, even though I am passing an empty array in useEffect().

**UPDATE**

After removing PersistGate JSX tags, it works fine. Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: what's wrong with that? you must initialize the `current` property before use it.

Comment: Shouldn't react initialise the current value?

Comment: The `useRef` hook still needs to be initialized to *something* before the first use. It isn't possible for react to know what you want that initial value to be. Can you disclose more of the component code, especially where `navigationRef.current` is set to be able to invoke `getRootState`?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/    

I am trying to follow this documentation.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Are you using the right version of the documentation? What does your package.json look like? You are correct that react should set `navigationRef ` when you do `ref={navigationRef}` and the ref should have been set before the hook executes.

Comment: I am using {"react": "16.13.1", "react-native": "0.61.5",}

Comment: @HMR,  The error is resolved when I remove PersitGate tags. Any ideas to what can be the root cause for this?

Comment: @DrewReese he error is resolved when I remove PersitGate tags. Any ideas to what can be the root cause for this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no, but feel free to update your question with these new details. Perusing the `react-persist` docs I think it may be because the `PersisGate` is rendering the `loading` prop, which is null, and thus the ref isn't attached to any UI element.

Comment: @DrewReese. I also thought that, but the error was still there when I used a component instead of just null. However extracting the complete navigation component including Navigation container into a new component and the using useEffect hook there resolved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working when I extract the complete `<NavigationContainer>` in a separate component and use `useEffect` there. Don't know what was the root cause still.

Answer (score 1):

It's only undefined on load. What you want is to use a useCallback since you are setting the ref after load. check out https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node